# Can't figure out the right loop in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am a newbie.

This is my spider:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from ampa.items import AmpaItem

class AmpaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "ampa"
    allowed_domains = ['website']
    start_urls = ['website/page']


rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('associados?', ), deny=('associado/', )), callback='parse_page', follow=True),)

def parse_page(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = AmpaItem()
    farmers = hxs.select('//div[@class="span-24 tx_left"]')
    item['nome'] = farmers.select('//div/h3[@class="titulo"]/a/text()').extract()
    item['phone'] = farmers.select('//div/span[@class="chamada"]/a[contains(text(), "Telefone")]/text()').extract() 
    item['email'] = farmers.select('//div/span[@class="chamada"]/a[contains(text(), "E-mail")]/text()').extract()
    print item.values()
    return item
```

This is my pipeline:

```
class CsvWriterPipeline(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.csvwriter = csv.writer(open('items.csv', 'wb'))

def process_item(self, item, ampa):
    self.csvwriter.writerow([item['nome'], item['phone'], item['email']])   
    return item
```

Each page of the website has a list of names, phones and e-mails. The code above will output a csv file with three columns and one row for each page. In the first column, each cell is a list of all names in that page, in the second column they are a list of all phones and in the third column they are a list of all e-mails.

**What I really want to do is to have each name, phone and e-mail in individual rows.** I tried to do it by looping through each item, but it only prints the first name, phone and e-mail on each page. (Is it because callback moves the crawler to the next URL each time the function spider returns an item) (Does it???)

How would you go about that?

Here is the item:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class AmpaItem(Item):
nome = Field()
phone = Field()
email = Field()
```

Comment: can you print what `item` is inside the `process_item` function it doesn't look like it should be a list of emails at all...

Comment: in your spreadsheet viewer are you making sure that you are opening the csv with ',' as the delimiter?

Comment: Hi dm03514, I used the delimiter, but it still won't separate the items.

Comment: can you post what an example `item` when it is inside `process_item` before you save it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by changing my pipeline:

```
import csv
import itertools

class CsvWriterPipeline(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.csvwriter = csv.writer(open('items.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=',')

def process_item(self, item, ampa):
    for i,n,k in itertools.izip(item['nome'],item['phone'],item['email']):  
        self.csvwriter.writerow([i,n,k])    
    return item
```

Thaks DrColossos and  dm03514!!

This was my first question on stackoverflow!!

Comment: As a side note, you may wish to use feed exports (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html) to create the CSV. This could make your life easier and your code shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your use of the plural in `farmes`, I assume there are many farmers on the page. So you expression will likely return a collection of farmers.

Can you loop through the result of farmers and yield each item?

```
#pseudocode
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
farmers = hxs.select('//div[@class="span-24 tx_left"]')
for farmer in farmer:
    item = AmpaItem()
    #be sure to select only one desired farmer here
    item['nome'] = farmers.select('//div/h3[@class="titulo"]/a/text()').extract()
    item['phone'] = farmers.select('//div/span[@class="chamada"]/a[contains(text(), "Telefone")]/text()').extract() 
    item['email'] = farmers.select('//div/span[@class="chamada"]/a[contains(text(), "E-mail")]/text()').extract()
    yield item
```

Comment: DrColossos, Yes, there are several farmers per page. I'd tried to loop through the result of farmers before and it either returns all the farmers in one cell or else it just returns the first farmer on each page. I wonder if it is being called by the callback?

Comment: If you post the link to the actuel website, it will be easier. It might by just a problem with the XPath expression

Comment: www.ampa.com.br/home/associados/

Comment: The link is above, DrColossos. I appreciate your help. Struggling to learn Scrapy here...